# Add in table column if count = 0 mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table that contains (id:Int, userName:Varchar, roomName:Varchar, read:Boolean) and what I want to do is to select the number of read which are false by username and group by roomName. For example if i have this values:

```
id UN  RN  read 
1   a   a   0
2   a   a   1
7   a   b   0
8   a   b   0
9   a   b   0
10  a   b   1
11  a   c   1
```

i would like that my query to return:

```
a   a   1
a   b   3
a   c   0
```

but it only returns:

```
a   a   1
a   b   3
```

I tried this approach:

```
select userName, roomName, 
        case when count(`read`) > 0 then  count(`read`) end as x 
from message 
where userName = "a" 
   && `read` = false  
group by roomName ;
```

and also this:

```
select userName, roomName, 
        if(count(`read`) = 0, 0,count('read'))  
from message 
where userName = "a" 
   && `read` = false  
group by roomName ;
```

but noneof them work. How should I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation. For this to do what you want, you need to remove the filter on `read` from `where` clause (otherwise rooms without `read`s are filtered out):

```
select userName, roomName, sum(read) as x 
from message 
where userName = 'a'  
group by userName, roomName;
```

Note that the standard syntax to declare string literals is to use single quotes (MySQL allows double quotes, but in the SQL standard they are meant to define identifiers, so I would not recommend using them).